# How does [...new set(array)] work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Consider:

```
const ages = [26, 27, 26, 26, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30]
const uniqueAges = [...new Set(ages)]

console.log(uniqueAges) // [26,27,28,29,30]
```

I know the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). I searched about *set*, and I didn't find an explanation about how it works.

How can I set *comparison* of items and find similar items?

If set, use a loop in the comparison.

Comment: one mathematical property of a set is that is contains unique values. You convert the array to a set and spread the result back into an array. This is an idiomatic way to get an array with unique values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [es6 unique array of objects with set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997067/es6-unique-array-of-objects-with-set)

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for information on `Set`s. Essentially a Set is a collection of unique values - ie it can't contain duplicates. So `new Set(ages)` is a Set containing all the values in `ages`, which duplicates necessarily removed. Then the spread operator just converts this back into an array - the overall effect being to just remove duplicates from the array.

Comment: so this use a loop in this operation ?
and thank you guys

Comment: Related: *[What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set can only contain unique values; here is what constitutes an equal value according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality):

> Because each value in the `Set` has to be unique, the value equality will be checked. In an earlier version of ECMAScript specification, this was not based on the same algorithm as the one used in the `===` operator. Specifically, for `Set`s, `+0` (which is strictly equal to `-0`) and `-0` were different values. However, this was changed in the ECMAScript 2015 specification. See "Key equality for `-0` and `0`" in the browser compatibility table for details.
>
> `NaN` and `undefined` can also be stored in a `Set`. All `NaN` values are equated (i.e. `NaN` is considered the same as `NaN`, even though `NaN !== NaN`).

There is an implicit loop in creation of the `Set`, using the [iterable interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) of the passed array. There is also a loop in `...`, which unpacks an iterable.

However, checking whether an element is already in `Set` is not done using a loop - for all intents and purposes you can think of a `Set` as a dictionary with only keys, and no values. The code is almost the same as:

```js
const ages = [26, 27, 26, 26, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30]

const temp = {};
for (const age of ages) {
  temp[age] = true;
}

const uniqueAges = [];
for (const age in temp) {
  uniqueAges.push(age);
}

console.log(uniqueAges);
```

I am intentionally writing this "low tech" way to illustrate what is going on; notice that object keys are always strings so the result will be stringified. Using a `Map` or also storing ages as *values* would make it much more similar in effect to OP's code, but I wanted to keep it simple for the sake of illustration.